# ЧПУ и mod_rewrite, замена вопроса на слэш

Tags: php, веб-программирование, mod-rewrite

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите как прописать так, чтобы мой текущий URL:
`http://site.ru/page?p=var`

выглядел так:

`http://site.ru/page/var`

P.S. "page" это "page.php" просто скрыто расширение

Ну и соответственно, чтобы обращение по второму адресу вело куда нужно.

Comment: Так вам такой `http://site.ru/page/var` вид урл надо формировать в php, когда страницу юзеру отдаете.

Comment: http://site-on.net/optimization/4-sef-url-mod-rewrite тут прочитай, подробнее написано, сам по нему учился

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/?$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
```